# Datamining library for .NET

Tags: .net, data-mining

Does anybody know about any dataming libraries for .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ADOMD.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483.aspx), it's Microsoft's .NET data provider for communicating with SQL Server Analysis Services.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [SQL Server Analysis Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510517.aspx)?